# Question about conditional types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In the following example:

```
class A {}
class B {}
type p<T> = T extends A ? A : B;
type x = p<A>;
type y = p<B>;
```

Type of 'x' is displayed as A, which is right, but the type of 'y' is still being displayed as A whereas it should have been Y. Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your types `A` and `B` are equivalent. Therefore TypeScript decides to not distinguish them.

Write

```
class A { a = '' }
class B { b = '' }
class C extends A { c = '' }
```

such that the types are really different and not compatible, then you will see that for

```
type x = p<A>;
type y = p<B>;
type z = p<C>;
```

we have `x: A`, `y: B` and `z: A`.

Notice that, if `B` contains the same members as `A` (`a` instead of `b`), it will again behave exactly like `A`.

---

Update:

The phenomenon is called structural typing.

While your original empty classes `A` and `B` can be assigned to each other (which implies that `B extends A` is true), at runtime they are distinguishable - but that is not covered by the type system (deliberately).

I have found a nice blog post with an extensive description about conditional types and more here: https://artsy.github.io/blog/2018/11/21/conditional-types-in-typescript/